# If $f(x)=2x-4$, What would the following graph of $3f(x+2)$ look like?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

To do this problem I substituted the $$(x+2)$$ as the x in the equation

$$ 3f(x+2)=2(x+2)-4$$
$$3f(x+2)=2x+4-4$$
$$3f(x+2)=2x$$
$$3f(x+2)/3=2x/3$$

when i graphed the equation I did not get the answer stated as the answer choice. What did i do wrong?

Comment: Vertical stretch by factor of $3$ and move $2$ units over.

Comment: $3f(x+2)=3\left[2(x+2)-4\right]$

Comment: @MathMajor In this case, it's fine, but I must point out that in general, one should be careful about the order of operations, when it comes to transformations.

Comment: @semiclassical So multiply 2 first and than by 3? I thought i should've divided it by 3?

Comment: @pjs36 Yes, agreed.

Comment: There's no reason to divide by 3 in here: You plug in some value of $x$, add $2$ to it, apply $f$ to it, and then multiply by 3.

Answer (score 2):

Begin with the graph of $f$.

Move it two to the left to get the graph of $y= f(x + 2)$.

Now stretch vertically by a factor of 3 to get the graph of $y = 3 f(x + 2)$.

Comment: so left two units and from there up 3 units and 1 units over?

Comment: No.  Read what I said.

Answer (score 2):

The graph of $f(x)=2x-4$ is a straight line; if I stretch/shift things (as I do by multiplying by a constant overall and replacing $x\to x+2$) the graph will still be that of a straight line. But when $x=-2$ one has $3f(0)=3(-4)=-12$, and for $x=0$ one has $3f(2)=3(0)=0$. Hence the new graph will be a line through the points $(-2,-12)$ and $(0,0)$, corresponding to the graph of $y=6x$.

Comment: how did u get x=-2?

Comment: @MATHASKER  I picked a point arbitrarily and tried it. I could've instead taken, say, $x=131$ and gotten instead $3f(133)=3(262)=786$. So the point $(131,768)$ should also be on the line. (And it is!)